# Using genymotion plugin for gradle in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, genymotion

I was trying to load an android studio project on eclipse. I found out that i would have to install the gradle plugin. I figured it all out and i was able to successfully load the project into eclipse.

I always use Genymotion as an emulator with eclipse. As now i've loaded a gradle project into my eclipse i'm seeing the following options to run the app.

I am unable to find a plugin for this or anything to run this app on genymotion

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MDnw.png

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The Genymotion Gradle plugin is available.
Here is [the documentation](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/gradle-plugin) to use it on your project.
This plugin will allows you to create, launch and configure Genymotion devices directly from your build.gradle file.

*NB: You will need Genymotion 2.5.0 or higher.*

Important, **the Gradle plugin for Genymotion is not mandatory** to simply install/test/debug your app from your IDE.

Since your project is an Android Gradle project, you can build your app running the command `gradlew assembleDebug` task (or click on "Run" button on your IDE). This will automatically find all Android devices connected to your computer through adb. It can be emulators like Genymotion or real devices.

So, you only have to manually launch the Genymotion device(s) you want to work with before compiling your app and it will automatically be installed on the connected Android devices.